# mysql joins with one to many, many to one relations and no redundant data

Tags: mysql, join, relational-database

I just googled around but couldn't find any perfect answer to my question. I am trying to join three tables orders, payment_milestone, invoices the relation between tables is like this:

orders to payment_milestone (one to many) one order can have many payment_milestone related to it may be 25%, 50%, and 25% on different dates.

now after the payment_milestone time reached the invoice will be generated and in invoices table, there will be order_id and payment_milestone_id

so, when I joined them like this:

```
SELECT 
inv.invoice_id, ord.sub_total, ord.vat_added, pm.pay_date, pm.percentage
FROM orders ord
INNER JOIN
payment_milestone pm ON ord.order_id = pm.order_id 
INNER JOIN 
invoices inv ON ord.order_id = inv.order_id
```

it returned me:
[this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsEsU.jpg) which is redundant

I used `GROUP BY` clause and it produced this result:
[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lsEsU.jpg)

the result I want is this:

```
invoice_id      sub_total        vat_added        pay_date       percentage
----------------------------------------------------------------------------
11              40000.00         2000.00          2018-09-20     53
12              40000.00         2000.00          2018-09-22     47
13              45360.00         2268.00          2018-09-27     100
```

I can't figure out where I'm doing wrong in query.

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of joining between payment_milestone and invoices table, the join should be on `payment_milestone_id` not `order_id`. As I understand, from your limited problem statement, that for every `payment_milestone_id`, a `invoice_id` is generated.

Try the following instead:

```
SELECT 
  inv.invoice_id, 
  ord.sub_total, 
  ord.vat_added, 
  pm.pay_date, 
  pm.percentage
FROM orders AS ord
INNER JOIN
  payment_milestone AS pm ON ord.order_id = pm.order_id 
INNER JOIN 
  invoices AS inv ON pm.payment_milestone_id = inv.payment_milestone_id
```

Comment: is this **AS** clause clause necessary

Comment: @MahmoodHussain happy to help :) . `AS` clause is not necessary, but it helps in clearer reading of the query, that is why I prefer to use it